# Error to try compile with gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-construction

I'm trying to compile SNNS (Stuttgart Neural Network Simulator) is a software simulator for neural networks on Unix, but I got the following error message:

```
Ignore possible error messages for the following command:
ranlib  libfunc.a
END OF COMMANDS THAT MAY FAIL

make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/fer/Desktop/SNNSv4.3/kernel/sources'

end of (re)making kernel libraries

gcc   snns2c.o snns2clib.o ../../kernel/sources/libkernel.a ../../kernel/sources/libfunc.a -lm -ll  -o snns2c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But I don't know what I need to install, do you have an idea about this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think `-ll` is referring to the lex library [`libl`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19683-01/816-0218/6m6nirqlp/index.html), as per [this message](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2000-01/msg00293.html). You may need to modify that make file to link against [flex](http://www.faqs.org/docs/linux_scratch/appendixa/flex.html).

Comment: It might be helpful to mention that at one time the Flex library was `-lfl`.  However, it may be that more modern versions of Flex do not need a library at all - or, rather, the `/usr/lib64/libfl.a` on RHEL only contains dummy versions of `main()` and `yywrap()`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem after installing `flex` from the distro's official repository.